# Adverb く + は to form expressions

Tags: grammar

Seeing the sentence

詳しくはプロフィールを見てください。

I understand that 詳しくは means "for more details; for further information".

However, taking into account that 詳しくは is the result of turning 詳しい into an adverb and adding the particle は, **I would like to know if you can do the same with other i-adjectives to form expressions. If so, could you please give me some examples?**

Besides, **may "Adjective-i → Adverb く + は" be considered as a grammar construction? Would there be any similar process with na-adjectives?**

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the 6 entry for は　in スーパー大辞林 :

> 動作・作用の行われる条件・事態を表す。現代語では「ては」の形で用いられるが，古語では「ずは」「くは」「しくは」などの形をとることもある。「不正があって―ならない」「おこられて―大変だ」「会社として―万全の備えをするつもりです」「忘れて―夢かとぞ思ふ/伊勢
> 83」「あらたまの年の緒(オ)長くあひ見ず―恋しくあるべし/万葉
> 4408」「鶯の谷よりいづるこゑなく―春くることをたれかしらまし/古今（春上）」「恋しく―形見にせよとわが背子が植ゑし秋萩/万葉 2119

translation:

> Indicates a condition or situation in which an action or an effect
> takes place. In modern language it is used in the
> 「ては」form, but in archaic Japanese it sometimes takes the form
> 「ずは」「くは」「しくは」, etc.

So apparently しくは is a form from old japanese that is still used in modern japanese .

> I would like to know if you can do the same with other i-adjectives to
> form expressions. If so, could you please give me some examples?

As far as i have searched it does actually , here is an example from japanese media that i searched :

1 正しくは 天空魔な Strictly speaking, it's Sky Magic.
fairy tail

Comment: 2-5 are actually not instances of the grammar that OP (and your quote) are talking about, but another construction altogether that has an emphatic or contrastive function.

Comment: Thank you I edited  it, thies two construction can overlap  !